Serve private images with access-token guard
I developed an application with access-token guard (instead of session).
When user is logged, back-end generates an access token and returns it to front-end.
For future requests, the front-end adds a header to each request:
Authorization: "Bearer {xxxxxxxxxx}"

It works great, but now I have a problem - I need to serve private media files (images, documents and audio) and need to keep them protected from other users.
What is the best approach to do it? It looks to me quite insecure to add the access-token as a query parameter of GET method.
